# JavaScript test if date (in string format) is more than 30 days ago

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the date in a string format like so `'11/2/2009'` (m/d/yyyy)

I need to test if that is greater than 30 days ago.

Whats the easiest and least error-prone way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
var then = new Date("11/2/2009").getTime(),
    now  = new Date().getTime(),
    thirtyDaysInMilliseconds = 2592000000;
if (now - then > thirtyDaysInMilliseconds) { doSomething(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to be sure your date meets the format (MM-DD-YYYY), but this should work:

```
var olddate = "11/02/2009"
var dt = Date.parse( olddate );
return ( ( Date.getTime() - dt.getTime() ) < 2592000000 );
```